# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors but no $

Tags: r

I keep getting the error:

`Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

when applying the function fitMCMC from package MSGARCH.

However, I make no use of `$`.

Here you are my code:

```
ts <- ts %>% mutate(asofdate = lubridate::ymd(asofdate)) ## from fct to date
ts <- ts %>% mutate(ret = high / dplyr::lag(high,1) - 1) %>% drop_na() 
j <- 1 ## looping in (1:400)
n <- round(0.7*nrow(ts))
set <- ts[j:n+j,] 
spec <- CreateSpec(variance.spec = list("gjrGARCH"),
                   distribution.spec = list("sged"),
                   switch.spec = list(do.mix = FALSE, 5))
fit <- MSGARCH::FitMCMC(spec, getElement(set, 'ret'))
```

where `set` is a tibble containing a column named `ret` and of type `dbl`.

```
structure(list(asofdate = structure(c(10961, 10962, 10963, 10966, 
10967, 10968, 10969, 10970, 10974, 10975), class = "Date"), high = c(1413.27, 
1411.9, 1441.47, 1464.36, 1458.66, 1442.6, 1454.2, 1473, 1465.15, 
1461.39), ret = c(-0.0288272563598632, -0.000969383061976803, 
0.0209434095899144, 0.0158796228849716, -0.00389248545439635, 
-0.0110101051650145, 0.00804103701649805, 0.0129280704167238, 
-0.0053292600135777, -0.00256629014094123)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("asofdate", 
"high", "ret"))
```

I also tried:

1. `getElements` but returning same error
2. `set['ret']` but returning `Error in f_check_y(data) : y must be numeric`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can use ```dput(head(df, 20))``` to share a snipped of your dataset, this will make it a lot easier to recreate your problem.

Comment: I encountered the same error and  I forgot how I solved. But in my case, it came from some wrong code. So, the error message is useless, you should find some wrong code.

Comment: I'm getting `Error in getElement(set, "ret") : object 'set' not found` with your code.

Comment: Thanks you all, I have added the part of the code where set comes from and the result of ```dput(head(set,20))```

Comment: Try raising an issue here: https://github.com/keblu/MSGARCH

Comment: What is in the `ts` object?